# python os.popen is not working for wait method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to automate some manual steps using python, i am opening new command prompt using os.popen and running docker compose up .. its opening new cmd and running the docker command, now i want run the next set of commands after docker command is up ... python script has to wait till that time, i tried with below code but its not working.
I tried with subprocess.Popen which has wait method but its not opening new cmd,it is running in python script running command prompt only ..
p=os.popen("Start cmd  /K docker-compose up")
p.wait

Answer (score 0):

I think the "start" command in windows cmd runs a process that launches a child process with the rest of the line as parameter, then finishes immediately. I guess that is why it does not wait until the docker-compose finishes (or whatever command you write after "start").

Example with Process IDs (PIDs):
Your python program (PID 1) runs the command "start cmd /K docker-compose up". The start process has PID 2. Start launches the "cmd /K docker-compose up" (a new process with PID 3). Start finishes. Your programs waits until PID 2 ends (it already ended so continues without waiting).

What you really wanted in the example is to wait until PID 3 finishes not PID 2.

Probably you can get the real PID of the child process with some tricks and then wait until it completes but you should consider if you really need the docker-compose to run in a separate window.

Comment: thanks for your reply. docker compose is up and running in command prompt .i want to get the status of the docker command, if its build correctly then it will display app services are running, once this is up then only i want to run other commands ..i want to get the status of the docker up command

Comment: I am sorry I am not an expert on docker or docker-compose so I cannot give you the exact solution, but maybe you can take the output from "docker ps" or "docker-compose ps" and use it for that. In python you can use `subprocess.Popen("here_goes_the_command", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")`  and it will return you the output of the command decoded as utf-8 text, so you can parse it with python